# curl request for login with password having special character in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, special-characters

I'm reading password from input file and login with that password. 
However if password has special character then its failing. 
How can i make it work for the passwords with or without special characters ? 
Have tried with '$pass' but looks it doesn't work.

```
ip="$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')"
pass="$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')"


output_json="$(curl -u admin:'$pass'  -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://$ip:443/admin -k)"
```

Comment: This should be `"${pass}"` for expanding variable

Comment: How to handle the variable if password contain $ ? ex : ```pass="sbxy$sT_i7d6I*7" echo "${pass}"
sbxy*7```

Comment: Use single quote for assinging variable and double for expansion. `$pass='sbxy$sT_i7d6I*7'
$echo $pass
sbxy$sT_i7d6I*7
$
`

Comment: Is this correct ?  ```  pass=' "$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')" ' 
output_json="$(curl -u admin:"${pass}"  -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://$ip:443/admin -k)" ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should [always quote variable expansions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F)
2. Use single-quotes to [disable variable expansions and other special characters](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Types_of_quoting)

Some issues with your current code:

- `echo $line` is not properly quoted, and will break on whitespace and other special characters; use `echo "$line"`

  - As @GordonDavisson suggested in the comments, `printf '%s\n' "$line"` would actually be safer than `echo`, which may not work correctly depending on the contents of `$line`
- `admin:'$pass'` will resolve to the literal characters `admin:$pass` being passed to `curl`; use `"admin:${pass}"`
- `https://$ip:443/admin` is also not properly quoted, use `"https://${ip}:443/admin"`
- If `$line` is being set with a [literal password in the script](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150580/46357) you'll want single-quotes to have the shell ignore special characters; `line='...,sbxy$sT_i7d6I*7'`

Comment: Actually, some versions of `echo` will mess up strings containing backslash or starting with dash. To reliably printing strings despite any weird characters, use `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Really a herestring would be more appropriate here, but I didn't feel like diving into that too.